# How to install artisan without composer?

Tags: php, windows, laravel, path, laravel-artisan

Is there is any way to install `artisan` without `composer` and internet access on window OS?.

Comment: Well, you have to have an internet connection at some point to download it whether it's composer or not... at which point you might as well use composer.

Comment: Nope. Composer is an integral part of setting up Laravel, and installing all dependencies. There was a project called LaraPack that bundled it up for you as a zip, but it hasn't been updated in over a year.

Comment: @jszobody thanks a lot, so how can we use LaraPack?

Comment: Artisan is just a PHP script that launches Laravel's version of Symfony console.  Running Artisan without Laravel won't do much for you.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Devon this is for a competition which has no internet access during it! and we should do many things in laravel, that's stupid but "artisan without internet" is what i'm looking for, todays!

Comment: Open up artisan and look at the code, it's not a binary file.